# Linked List, add a value after an node

Tags: linked-list

I am now learning about linked list, but I got stuck very soon.
I was reading the code by my lecturer and there is a method I don't really understand.

```
public class List { 
    public Item start = null;
    private class Item { 
        private int value;
        private Item next;
        private Item (int x, Item item) {
            value = x;
            next = item;
        }
    }
     public void insertAfter(Item item, int x) {
        if (item == null) {
            start = new Item(x, start);
        } else {
             item.next = new Item(x, item.next);
        }
    }
    public Item findValue(int x) {
        Item p = start;
        while (p != null && p.value != x) {
        p = p.next;
        }
        return p;
    }
```

say i have a list L
9->7->5->4->7->null
use the method item

```
L.findValue(7);
```

returns the node 7->5->4->7->null

and then i use

```
L.insertAfter(item, 100);
```

why would the list now become 
9->7->100->5->4->7->null?????

the problem i am seeing here is the void method does not modify the start node but the "item" which is the input only.
I thought i would only modify "item" only..

What am I missing here????

Comment: Your snippet that shows the insertAfter call references a variable labelled 'item'.... it will depend where in the LL that Item sits (not necessarily the 'value' property given your findValue function returns the 'first' instance of the the value)

Comment: yes i understand that the findValue return the first instance. therefore if i use L.insertAfter(item, 100); this means i will add 100 after the first 7, but why can "item.next = new Item(x, item.next);" modify the "start" node of the list?